# sqlalchemy session.execute with positional arguments error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use positional arguments to be used in a lengthy insert query. But it doesnt seem to allow using positional arguments. I am using mysql. Below is the error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: List argument must consist only of tuples or dictionaries
```

sample query with placeholders

```
        query = "insert into test values(?,?,?)" 
        values = (1,2,3)
```

tried

```
        connection = session.connection()
        result = connection.execute(text(query), *values)

        result = session.execute(text(query), *values)

        result = connection.execute(text(query), values)

        result = session.execute(text(query), values)

        changed placeholder.
        query = "insert into test values(%s,%s,%s)"
```

As the actual query is much bigger , I prefer not to use dict/named arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLALchemy 2.0+ [does not support this functionality](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execute.params.*multiparams/**params) for the execute method of either sessions or connections. However it is possible to use a connection's [exec_driver_sql](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.exec_driver_sql) method in the same way as you would execute a query with a DB-API cursor directly.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
engine = sa.create_engine('mariadb+pymysql:///test', echo=True)
tbl = sa.Table('users', sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)

q = """SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE id = %s or name = %s"""

with engine.connect() as conn:
    rows = conn.exec_driver_sql(q, (1, 'Bob'))
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
```

If you are using a session, you can use [Session.connection()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.connection) to obtain a reference to the session's connection. This snippet shows how, and logs the connection object to demonstrate that the ORM and `exec_driver_sql`  use the same connection, to avoid transaction isolation issues.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm

engine = sa.create_engine('mariadb+pymysql:///test', echo=False)

# Set up a simple model mapped to an existing table.
metadata = sa.MetaData()
tbl = sa.Table('users', metadata, autoload_with=engine)

registry = orm.registry(metadata=metadata)

class User:
    pass

registry.map_imperatively(User, tbl)


@sa.event.listens_for(sa.Engine, 'before_cursor_execute', retval=False)
def log_connection_object(conn, cursor, statement, parameters, context, executemany):
    print(f'{conn=}')


q = """SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE id = %s or name = %s"""

with orm.Session(engine) as s:
    users = s.scalars(
        sa.select(User).where(sa.or_(User.id == 1, User.name == 'Bob'))
    ).all()
    rows = s.connection().exec_driver_sql(q, (1, 'Bob'))
```

The output shows both executions use the same connection:

```
conn=<sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection object at 0x7ff475bbe240>
conn=<sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection object at 0x7ff475bbe240>
```

Comment: Wow !!. Thanks a lot.!!  @snakecharmerb.  ChatGPT cannot replace SO :D..  Btw do you think if there is any down side of using this function. as obviously they omitted this option in execute method.

Comment: As long as you use the same connection as the session (I've edited the answer to show how) then there shouldn't be any issues (using a different connection might result in data inconsistencies due to transaction isolation). I suspect `Session.execute` doesn't support this in order to keep it simple.