# Use placeholder %s with SQLAlchemy 2.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I want/need to update my project from SQLAlchemy 1.4 to SQLAlchemy 2.x.

Is there a way to use the placehoder `%s` with a list of arguments in the `execute()`function without running the query multiple times?

This is how it worked in SQLALchemy 1.4:

```py
conn.execute(
    "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = %s AND age = %s",
    ['roy', 45]
)
```

But now it runs the query for each entry of the list.

I have used this over 100 times in my project, so I am not happy with this change unless the old way does not work.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77967038/5320906) answer your question?

Comment: I already found that. Now i see it must be a tuple not a list. thx